# angularjs filter product based on category and search bar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, categories, product

So, this is my first question in SO, I've googled and search in SO but haven't got what I want to solve my problem.
I'm building an ecommerce website using angularjs as frontend and JSON to get the data from my Backend Server.

I've successfully listed all the products using JSON and promise.
I separated the site like this : 
navigation bar : using categoryCtrl to get all the categories
main content : using storeCtrl to handle shopping cart, order, checkout
in the middle of main content using productCtrl to display all the product.

1. Do I need to separate Categories, Products, Stores in different Ctrl?
2. I want to have a filter function based on what I click in navigation page to refresh the products in other div using productCtrl
   NavigationPage :

```html
<ul side-navigation class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu" ng-controller="categoryController">
<li data-ng-repeat="cat in categoryList" ui-sref-active="active">
     <a ng-if="cat.level == 1" ui-sref="store({ id:cat.category_id })">
        <span class="nav-label">{{cat.category_name}}</span> 
     </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

and in my config.js is like this :

```js
$stateProvider
        .state('store/', {
            url: "/:id",
            templateUrl: "views/store.html",
            controller: storeController,
            resolve: {
                            qId: function ($stateParams) {
                                return $stateParams.id;
                            }
                        }
            
        })
```

and in my ProductController is like this :

```js
angular
.module('myapps')
.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope,productService,$modal, $stateParams){
    $scope.init = function(){
      var id = $stateParams.id;

      if(id == "")
        $scope.getAllProducts();
      else
        $scope.getAllProductsByCategory(id);
    }

    var id = $stateParams.id;

    $scope.getAllProducts = function(){
      productService.getAllProducts()
      .then(function(res){
        $scope.productList = productService.productList;
      }, function(err){
        //error result
        alert('failed');
      })
      
    }

    $scope.getAllProductsByCategory = function(id){
      productService.getProductByCategory(id)
      .then(function(res){
        $scope.productList = productService.productList;
      }, function(err){
        //error result
        alert('failed');
      })
    }


    $scope.init();
});
```

But still didn't make it to refresh the product list.

to update the Product List in another div in main content :

```html
<div class="row" ng-controller="ProductController">
    <div class="product-list">
        <div class="product-box" data-ng-repeat="product in productList.product">
            
<div class="product-name">       
  {{product.product_name}}
</div>
<div class="product-price">
{{product.price | number}} ,-
</div>
 
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

3. I want to have searchbox in another div to filter the products, it will call the function in productCtrl to get data from JSON based on keyword, but I still have no idea how to refresh the content as soon as the searchbox is entered with some value

Thank you so much for your help.